# Laravel - Video file validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is this how to validate a video file in laravel ?

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
  array(
    'file'  => 'mimes:mp4,mov,ogg | max:20000'
  ) 
);
```

because even if the file uploaded is a mov type, it will return that the file should be one of the types listed in the rule above.

---

*How I ended up solving it:*

As prompted from the answer's below I ended up storing the mime type for the uploaded file to a `$mime` variable like so:

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$mime = $file->getMimeType();
```

Then had to write an if statement to check for video mime types:

```
if ($mime == "video/x-flv" || $mime == "video/mp4" || $mime == "application/x-mpegURL" || $mime == "video/MP2T" || $mime == "video/3gpp" || $mime == "video/quicktime" || $mime == "video/x-msvideo" || $mime == "video/x-ms-wmv") 
{
  // process upload
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That code is checking for the extension but not the MIME type. You should use the appropriate MIME type:

```
 Video Type     Extension       MIME Type
Flash           .flv            video/x-flv
MPEG-4          .mp4            video/mp4
iPhone Index    .m3u8           application/x-mpegURL
iPhone Segment  .ts             video/MP2T
3GP Mobile      .3gp            video/3gpp
QuickTime       .mov            video/quicktime
A/V Interleave  .avi            video/x-msvideo
Windows Media   .wmv            video/x-ms-wmv
```

If you are not sure the MIME type of the file you are testing you can try `$file->getMimeType()`

Comment: so, if i am trying to upload only .mov file it should be like `'file'  => 'mimes:video/quicktime | max:20000` , because that wont let me process the form either...

Comment: Did you check it with getMimeType? try removing max also for debugging the mime type.

Comment: I removed the max size rule and i checked that the mime type is a quicktime one, because i am saving the file with the mime type in the database..

Comment: I wrote an if statement to check the mime type and got it working. Though, this is not what i was after, I wanted to use the validator so I could provide appropriate messages to the user. Thanks anyway, not sure why i can not add the rule with the `mimes`. Is there a way to add it to the rules instead of checking with an if statement ?

Comment: Try the same but with a custom validation: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 28):

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

You should add **qt** in types:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
  array(
    'file'  => 'mimes:mp4,mov,ogg,qt | max:20000'
  ) 
);
```

Comment: Great for video from iphone 5 at least.

Comment: II needed to validate mp4 videos and for some reason it couldn't, I put the "qt" validation in the mime and now it works

Comment: this should be good

Answer (score 22):

For other googlers searching mimes for video validation, use this:

```
'video' => 'mimetypes:video/x-ms-asf,video/x-flv,video/mp4,application/x-mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv,video/avi'
```

Comment: Nice list, I would also add in video/x-matroska for mkv files

Comment: I see that is easier to use extensions

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an older question, but I just ran into the same problem today. Laravel would not validate a .mov filetype, even if I had 'mov', 'quicktime', or 'video/quicktime' in the validator.  getMimeType() on the file was showing 'video/quicktime' so it seemed really odd.

Digging into Laravel's validator class, it seemed that it was using guessExtension() instead of getMimeType() to check the file.  When I put 'qt' as the mime type into the validator (which is what guessExtension() was returning) it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this meme type

```
$this->validate($req, [
      'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,ogx,oga,ogv,ogg,webm',
      ]);
```

This format working good for OGG file upload.

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, you do have not to use video/. I had this problem and I solved it. Use the below code for the solution.

```
$request->validate([
            "file"=>"required | mimes:mp4,x-flv,x-mpegURL,MP2T,3gpp,quicktime,x-msvideo,x-ms-wmv |max:9000000"
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Used `$file->getClientMimeType()` to get the mime type that validator seems to use.
Turns out one of the mp4 files had a mime type `video/x-m4v`