# Laravel Validation on video file not working

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am workng on video hosting website in laravel,

1. I have a from which user can enter data in fields
2. In form user can upload a video file

   {{ Form::file('filename', isset($movie->filename) ? $movie->filename: Input::old('filename')) }}

my validator code is given below

```
    $input = Input::all();
    $validator = Validator::make($input,
        array(
            // other validations working fine
            'filename' => 'required|mimes:video/mp4,video/x-flv,application/x-mpegURL,video/MP2T,video/3gpp,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv'
        ));
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378742/laravel-video-file-validation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246099/laravel-mime-video-extension-validation)

Even I have checked MIME type of a file for testing purpose via

```
dd(mime_content_type($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']));
```

it returns **video/mp4** , even it is in validation check. Moreover **required** validation is also working good.
Then why Mime Type validtion not working fine ?
Thanks

Comment: So what exactly happens in your validation? You say it's "not working fine" but that could mean any number of different problems are occurring. Do you get an error code? Incorrect output? The Flying Spaghetti Monster emerged from your monitor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `mimes` validator rule like this:

```php
'filename' => 'required|mimes:mp4,x-flv,x-mpegURL,MP2T,3gpp,quicktime,x-msvideo,x-ms-wmv'
```

Comment: Thanks for qucik response :) Working now !!

I followed the way mentioned in 2 links in my question.. did you see that ?

Comment: yup, that's not correct. If you try to search "laravel mimes mp4" on Google you'll see that you dont need to use ``video/`` in that rule.

Comment: I guess those awnser should be edited to save other's time :), Thanks by the way

Comment: Old question, but you need to change "quicktime" to "qt"

Comment: @RykWaters [nope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-mimetypes).

Comment: @limonte nice answer backed up with reasons for rejection. But from actual experience and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378742/laravel-video-file-validation?noredirect=1&lq=1 you'll see that it should be qt to actually work